# How to filter data samples which do not improve classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, data-cleaning, text-classification

I have a text dataset with noisy labels and an unbalanced shape.

There are various ways to find features which do not drive improvement in some metric, and help to prune those from the pipeline.

I cannot however find a way to throw away noisy / confusing samples.

One naive approach might be to run the model removing a single sample at a time and see if the metric improves or does not change - if that happens, throw away that sample.

Is there a name for such a technique? Or does it not exist for good reason :)

Comment: Noisy data would be basically Outliers. The Internet has a lot of threads on this. But not all the models are affected by it.

Comment: Why would you want to "clean" this noisy data? Depending on your goals, I believe that the best way to have a model or an analysis to be useful with real world data and in a production setting, is to be able to adapt to all possible types of inputs.

Comment: Its a valid point, but needs more information @Wajdi